# Timeout in DefaultHttpClient Class Android

Tags: android

I have created an Android application where I connect to a remote server php file to retrieve some information. Below is the code for that.

Here I want to add timeout with the connection such as the connection will timeout in 5 seconds.

Any idea how to do this.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","test"));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/test.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Regards,

Shankar

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the `HttpConnectionParams` of your `DefaultHttpClient`::

```
final HttpParams httpParameters = yourHttpClient.getParams();

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, connectionTimeOutSec * 1000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout        (httpParameters, socketTimeoutSec * 1000);
```

Comment: the time out is all well and good, but how to we catch the time out (the code as it is right now just fails silently when there is a timeout)

Comment: When it fails, this code throws an exception that you can catch and handle.

Comment: By "this" code, I meant the OP's code. Nowadays, according to Android's official blog, it is better to use HttpUrlConnection rather than DefaultHttpClient anyway.