# Android DefaultHttpClient connection reuse

Tags: java, android

I am using DefaultHttpClient for connection. What I would like to do is "keep checking if it's alive" and when timeed out, reconnect. How can I do that ? I tried that entity is not null the consumeContent. Is it not working for me.

Comment: A better approach might be to simply _assume_ it is alive and deal with it accordingly if it is not.

Comment: OK then how do deal with it when it's timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this is to set a [HttpRequestRetryHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpRequestRetryHandler.html) and deal with the retry accordingly.

```
client.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryHandler);
```

You can also adjust the timeout via the `HttpParams` as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229189/timeout-in-defaulthttpclient-class-android) which may suffice depending on your exact needs; however building in retry behavior is a good approach either way.

```
final HttpParams httpParameters = yourHttpClient.getParams();

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, connectionTimeOutSec * 1000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout        (httpParameters, socketTimeoutSec * 1000);
```